# v-if not updating on child component when object is updated

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a Form class that contains an errors object and a clearError method for when an input is updated so the error message goes away once they keydown.  **What isn't working is the help text doesn't go away on the keydown if I just delete one property**.

Stripped down:

```
class Form {

    clearError(field = null) {
        if (!field) {
            this.formErrors = {};
            return;
        }

        delete this.formErrors[field];
    }

    hasError(field) {
        return this.formErrors[field] !== undefined;
    }
}
```

In my input help component I have:

```
<span v-if="form.hasError(field)" v-text="form.getError(field)"></span>
```

In my main form I have:

```
<form @keydown="form.clearError($event.target.name)">
...
<input-help :form="form" field="email"></input-help>
```

The v-if works fine if I clear out formErrors in all (`form.clearError()`) but not if I just clear out one property on formErrors (`form.clearError('email')`).  I'm assuming there is some sort of cache I am running into.

I've logged the `$event.target.name`, it works fine, and I can see in the Vue dev tools that the `formErrors.email` property is removed, but the help text still remains as the v-if (in input-help) is not correctly computing the change in value.

Any idea how I can make this v-if update properly?  I'd rather not clear all errors, I want to only clear the error relating to the input that is modified.

Comment: Hey not sure if this is of any help but here is an example repo with basically what you are trying to accomplish https://github.com/laracasts/Vue-Forms/blob/master/public/js/app.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell Vue that your are trying to delete property that Vue doesn't know about. So instead of

```
delete this.formErrors[field];
```

use

```
Vue.delete(this.formErrors, field);
```

Comment: Thanks, this does work, but makes my class dependent on Vue.  Guess that is ok for this application.

Comment: `this.$delete(this.formErrors, field)` should also work.